# Eclipse ADT crashing every time when it starts

Tags: eclipse-adt

hey guys this is my eclipse.ini config file

```
-startup
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
 --launcher.library
 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
 -product
 com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
 --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 256M
 -showsplash 
  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
  -vm 
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_20\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
  --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
 256m
 --launcher.defaultAction
 openFile
 -vmargs
 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
  -Xms40m  
  -Xmx768m
  -Declipse.buildId=v22.0.4-741630

  -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla


#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000051220710, pid=3960, tid=4448
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64         compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xa0710]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of
```

And this hs_pid_error file that is created everytime I tried and added this line at the end "-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla" still it is crashing and giving the same error.

Comment: Try removing the empty line before `-D....=mozilla`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in Java 8 update 20, 64 bit server vm.
I get it all the time under windows 7 64 bit with different programs (eg. IntelliJ Idea 13, Tomcat 7). 
Java 8 update 20 seems to be (almost) unusable.
How did this buggy version make it into a release version?
Whatever, I will try to downgrade to Java 8 update 11 in order to get around this.

Here is an excerpt of one of my crashes:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000507b0710, pid=3992, tid=18132
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_20-b26) (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.20-b23 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xa0710]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000001e8a800):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000015780000,0x0000000015880000] [id=18132]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000470e8dc60

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000002, RBX=0x000000067b6b42f0, RCX=0x000000067b6b42f0, RDX=0x0000000470e8dc58
RSP=0x000000001587f968, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x00000000384c1e80, RDI=0x000000003f5e9fc0
R8 =0x00000000384c1e80, R9 =0x0000000000000016, R10=0x000000000000000c, R11=0x000000000000000c
R12=0x0000000050d33328, R13=0x0065006d0061006e, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000001e8af20
RIP=0x00000000507b0710, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001587f968)
0x000000001587f968:   0000000050aee132 000000067b6b52c8
0x000000001587f978:   0000000000000005 00000000384c1e80
0x000000001587f988:   00000000384c1e80 000000068e1d0020
0x000000001587f998:   0000000000001000 0000000000000048
0x000000001587f9a8:   000007fe00000001 0000000000000000
0x000000001587f9b8:   0000000001e86201 0000000050d33328
0x000000001587f9c8:   0000000050aee4c0 000000068e1d2b64
0x000000001587f9d8:   0000000000000000 00000000384c1e80
0x000000001587f9e8:   000000003f5e9fc0 000000068e1d2b64
0x000000001587f9f8:   0000000050aeeea5 0000000000000005
0x000000001587fa08:   0000000050af1583 000000068dc89a58
0x000000001587fa18:   0000000050811fd3 000000068dc89a3d
0x000000001587fa28:   000000068dc89a3d 000000eb000000af
0x000000001587fa38:   00000384000002f2 000000068da70020
0x000000001587fa48:   0000000050aee8eb 000000eb000000b0
0x000000001587fa58:   00000384000002f2 0000000001e8af10 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000507b0710)
0x00000000507b06f0:   48 8d 05 21 28 51 00 48 89 44 24 30 e8 cf 35 1d
0x00000000507b0700:   00 48 81 c4 c0 00 00 00 5b c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc
0x00000000507b0710:   44 8b 42 08 4c 8b ca 45 85 c0 7e 0e 41 f6 c0 01
0x00000000507b0720:   75 57 41 c1 f8 03 41 8b c0 c3 79 4d 80 3d e6 1b
```